# How to send smtp through google? when using google apps standard edition

Tags: gmail, smtp

I have some C# code that I use for my contact form. I know it works and is not the issue. I signed up a few weeks ago and have been slowly moving away from my hosting sites mail servers.

I setup a few accounts already with google apps and when I send emails with them and to them through thunderbird they receive it.

Now I am trying to use google as my smtp to send out emails. However it does not work(I don't get really get an error expect for a timeout error as it can't send the email).

I tried using this

```
SMTP Host: smtp.gmail.com
username: support@mydomain.com
password: 1234567
port: 587
```

However this does not work. Do I need to use some other host from google since I am using my own domain name(even though  I am using their services still?)

Comment: Does your app login to the server first before sending the mail ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need authentication to use Google's SMTP servers.
use either TLS/STARTTL on port 587 or SSL on port 465.

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that I tried both port 587 and 465.

Comment: you are actually using TLS or SSL rather than straight SMTP?

Comment: what do you mean by "straight smtp"?

Comment: He means that just by using port 587 or 465 doesn't mean that you are using the encryption that Google requires.  Your SMTP client must be configured to use SSL or TLS in order for it to work.